# Flutter Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor on dialog pop

Tags: flutter

I'm having an issue trying to pop a dialog that contains a circle loader. I actually pop fine once my data is loaded, but in debug mode it's showing an exception that I can't figure out how to fix.

I have a stateful screen that on init I use the following code:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  showLoading();
});
```

The method `showLoading` is as follows:

```
void showLoading() {
  //let's show the loading bar
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      dialogContext = context;
      return AppLoader();
    },
  );
}
```

Where AppLoader simply returns:

```
class AppLoader extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              height: 80.0,
              width: 80.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

dialogContent is defined in the initial of the class as:

```
late BuildContext dialogcontext;
```

The main bulk of my code looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: ColorConstant.gray100,
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorConstant.gray100,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          getMainListViewUI(),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget getMainListViewUI() {
  return FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listViews.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return listViews[index];
          },
        );
    },
  );
}
```

Basically, the issue that I have is that when I finish getting the data from (getData()), I use:

```
Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
```

This works great: it removes the circle loader and I can see the screen behind it, no issues, no errors. However, if I run in debug mode, when I do a hotsync, it always shows me the error:
`Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor on dialog pop`

I understand that this is because of the Navigator.pop that I am doing, but I don't get it. I've defined the dialogContext, which is what I am passing to the showDialog, and that's what I am popping. I've also tried setting a scheduled navigator, but again, same issue.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if widget is mounted or not. This problem is likely to occur when you pass a context and have async function. Can you add this before navigation and see if problem is solved

```
if(!mounted) return;
```

Comment: But do you mean to put Navigtor.pop inside that if statment if the widget is mounted? If so, i tried that as well and it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: No more like you put this statement just before you use context so if widget is not mounted, navigation will not function

Comment: ahh, got you! ok ill give it a shot and revert back.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue is the my getData method was being called multiple times, the first time it pops the loading widget fine, after that it would throw the error which is correct since the loading widget no longer exists.